# Do Playwright browser contexts opened manually need to be closed?

Tags: playwright

If I am not using the `context` test fixture, but instead `browser` and calling `browser.newContext()`, should I close these contexts at the end of the test? Or can they be garbage-collected and closed automatically?

If I need to close them, I'd expect the documentation or examples to say so somewhere but couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes you should close them after you don't need them anymore, in e.g. afterAll or afterEach depending on your use-case. Otherwise it will yield to memory leaks. For documentation suggestions, please file an issue on GitHub.